# My mesh keeps deforming and random vertices merge during animation after I ctr+j a cube

Tags: animation, mesh, edges, geometry, surface-deform

I can usually just go back a few steps to fix the glitch but when I try to merge them again it will corrupt the same way as soon as I press play. There are no bones and adding them didn't help. I've also ensured manually that each object's origin is at the same coordinates. Just now, I opened the file and I've found it's corrupted again. I've been trying to figure this out for days but it takes time because I keep having to remake the objects that get corrupted. I'm trying to add a white trim around the door and it's worked on only one of the two. Sometimes it doesn't corrupt right away. I can play the animation endlessly and move on to play with the rest of the design. I might even be able to continue working on it *after* saving and reopening it before it does this. The animation still works fine though...

[image: Bad Mesh]

[image: Working door.]

The one that isn't corrupted has a few more vertices because of the lock and knot in it but it doesn't account for the number lost between the doors.

I *had* this one working for a while and would like to recreate it.

[image: Final design]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have animated objects with bones and you try to join them into one object? Why?

Comment: Incorrect, there are no bones. For now, I've simply made the door a parent to the frame I wanted to merge onto it. Not sure why the frame (cube mesh) only merged/joined correctly on one door and not the other. Both doors are separate objects, as are the handles.

Comment: do you have a boolean modifier somewhere? Maybe it would make things simpler if you could upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to embed the download link.